# Identity-preserving group operations besides conjugation and commutation?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with identity denoted $1$. Let $\alpha$ denote an arbitrary element of $G$. The following two classes of group operations $f_\alpha : G \to G$ have the property that $f_\alpha(1) = 1$ for every $\alpha$.

1. Conjugate the input by $\alpha$, i.e. $f_\alpha(x) = \alpha \cdot x \cdot \alpha^{-1}$.
2. Form the commutator of the input and $\alpha$, i.e. $f_\alpha(x) = \alpha \cdot x \cdot \alpha^{-1} \cdot x^{-1}$.

Are there other common/useful/interesting (subjectively defined) classes of functions that are also identity-preserving?

Comment: I don't quite see the point of this...

Comment: Every group homomorphism preserves the identity.

Comment: This is a weird question, as user58512's comment show. Not to mention that the "subjectively defined" part is one of the weirdest ones, objectively speaking.

Comment: Must functions between groups, that we deal with, do preserve the identity. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the operation of a group $G$ on some object $X$ is just a group homomorphism from $G$ to the automorphism group of $X$. If $X$ is $G$ itself, two possibilities stand out:

- View $X=G$ only as a **set**. Then there is no reason to restrict oneself to actions that leave $1$ fixed. In fact, $G$ operates on itself by left multiplication and this does not leave $1$ fixed (unless $G=1$)
- View $X=G$ as a **group**. Then the automorphisms are group homomorphisms and as such leave $1$ fixed.

By the way, note that your second example is not even a group action. For example if $G$ is abelian and nontrivial, then $f_\alpha$ is not an automorphism of $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are aiming at, but ...

Let $f:G\rightarrow H$ be an arbitrary function and let $ a \in G$. Define a new function $ f^a $ by

$$ f^a(g) = f(a)^{-1}f(ag) $$

Then $ f^a $ is identity preserving. Furthermore this defines an action of G on the set of identity preserving functions and homomorphisms are precisely the singletons under this action. Pretty yes?